# Scrapy FormRequest redirect not wanted link

Tags: scrapy

I followed the basic Scrapy Login. It always works, but in this case, I had some problems. The FormRequest.from_response didn't request the **https://www.crowdfunder.com/user/validateLogin**, instead it always sent payload to **https://www.crowdfunder.com/user/signup**. I tried directly request the validateLogin with payload, but it responded with 404 Error. Any idea to help me solve this problem? Thanks in advance!!!

```
class CrowdfunderSpider(InitSpider):
    name = "crowdfunder"
    allowed_domains = ["crowdfunder.com"]
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.crowdfunder.com/',
    ]

    login_page = 'https://www.crowdfunder.com/user/login/'
    payload = {}

    def init_request(self):
        """This function is called before crawling starts."""
        return scrapy.Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

    def login(self, response):
        """Generate a login request."""
        self.payload = {'email': 'my_email',
                        'password': 'my_password'}

        # scrapy login
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata=self.payload, callback=self.check_login_response)

    def check_login_response(self, response):
        """Check the response returned by a login request to see if we are
        successfully logged in.
        """
        if 'https://www.crowdfunder.com/user/settings' == response.url:
            self.log("Successfully logged in. :) :) :)")
            # start the crawling
            return self.initialized()
        else:
            # login fail
            self.log("login failed :( :( :(")
```

Here is the payload and request link sent by clicking login in browser:

[payload and request url sent by clicking login button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKbyA.png)

Here is the log info:

```
2016-10-21 21:56:21 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.0 started (bot: crowdfunder_crawl)
2016-10-21 21:56:21 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'AJAXCRAWL_ENABLED': True, 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'crowdfunder_crawl.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['crowdfunder_crawl.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'crowdfunder_crawl'}
2016-10-21 21:56:21 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2016-10-21 21:56:21 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.ajaxcrawl.AjaxCrawlMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.chunked.ChunkedTransferMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2016-10-21 21:56:21 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']

2016-10-21 21:56:21 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2016-10-21 21:56:21 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened

2016-10-21 21:56:21 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

2016-10-21 21:56:21 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024

2016-10-21 21:56:21 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.crowdfunder.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)

2016-10-21 21:56:21 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.crowdfunder.com/user/login> from <GET https://www.crowdfunder.com/user/login/>

2016-10-21 21:56:22 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.crowdfunder.com/user/login> from <GET http://www.crowdfunder.com/user/login>

2016-10-21 21:56:22 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.crowdfunder.com/user/login> (referer: None)

2016-10-21 21:56:23 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://www.crowdfunder.com/user/signup> (referer: https://www.crowdfunder.com/user/login)

2016-10-21 21:56:23 [crowdfunder] DEBUG: login failed :( :( :(
2016-10-21 21:56:23 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-10-21 21:56:23 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1569,
 'downloader/request_count': 5,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 16313,
 'downloader/response_count': 5,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 22, 4, 56, 23, 232493),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 22, 4, 56, 21, 180030)}
2016-10-21 21:56:23 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormRequest.from_response(response)` by default uses the first form it finds. If you check what forms the page has you'd see:

```
In : response.xpath("//form")
Out: 
[<Selector xpath='//form' data='<form action="/user/signup" method="post'>,
 <Selector xpath='//form' data='<form action="/user/login" method="POST"'>,
 <Selector xpath='//form' data='<form action="/user/login" method="post"'>]
```

So the form you are looking for is not 1st one. The way to fix it is to use one of many `from_response` method parameters to specify which form to use.

Using `formxpath` is the most flexible and my personal favorite:

```
In : FormRequest.from_response(response, formxpath='//*[contains(@action,"login")]')
Out: <POST https://www.crowdfunder.com/user/login>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the help! I checked the /user/login page but I didn't find the form tag. It seems to have all forms in the home page.

Comment: @BowenLiu could you clarify a bit? The `user/login` page seems to redirects to itself two times then it contians 3 forms that I left in my answer. The second form contains all of the input fields and should be working with FormRequest.

Comment: Yes, it works using the second form. When using "https://www.crowdfunder.com/user/login" as the "self.login_page", the from_response didn't find any form item using response.xpath("//form"), but I did find all your three form items using homepage "https://www.crowdfunder.com", and it passed the login.